# React Native deep link app opening from background

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

Ive enabled deep linking and everything works great when the application opens. When I open the app from a closed state using the url moderatorapp://hello it logs the correct url, but it does not work when the app is deep linked while being opened from a background state. My code is as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Storage.clear();
    Storage.getItem('data_moderator')
        .then(_data => {
            if (_data && _data.tokens) {
                this.autoLogin(_data.tokens);
            } else {
                Actions.loginForm();
            }
        }
    );

    Linking.getInitialURL()
        .then(url => {
            console.log('Initial Url then ', url);
            if (url) {
                console.log('Initial Url ', url);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}
```

This is obviously because the componentDidMount method is not being called at that point.

***What I have tried:***

I attempted to wrap the Linking code inside of an event that detects the application entering into the active state and it doesn't work, it logs the same url from the initial attempt when the app was closed. When I attempt to deep link into the app from the background state using the url moderatorapp://goodbye it logs the moderatorapp://hello. So it somehow is not updating.

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', (state) => {
    if (state === 'active') {
        console.log('state active');
        Linking.getInitialURL()
            .then(url => {
                console.log('Initial Url then ', url);
                if (url) {
                    console.log('Initial Url ', url);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    if(state === 'background'){
        console.log('background');
    }
});
```

Im really new to React Native, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html Specifically:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
openURL:(NSURL *)url
options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
   {
return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

Apple changed the api for linking so if you are targeting ios 9 or newer, you need this code in your AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have answered this for the benefit of others. I found this same information in React Native doc. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#getinitialurl

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for benefit! You saved my day. getInitialURL() really what been need to use.

Comment: If you're using expo, see https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2063

Answer (score 0):

The deep linking is working as expected for me even the app is in `background`. Please check the below specifications.

> Node Version : v12.18.x **OR Greater**
> NPM Version : v6.14.x **OR Greater**
> react-native-cli : 2.0.1
> react-native : 0.63.x **OR Greater**

Please check if you have added below line in your `AppDelegate.m`.

> #import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

It must be added above `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` line. Adding it below this line will cause failing of build while Archiving it for release.

Please check if you have added below code in your `AppDelegate.m` which is responsible for deep linking.

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
> openURL:(NSURL *)url
> options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
> {
> return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
> }

It will work for app cold boot, but it will not work if your app is in `background`. For this, you need to add below code in your `AppDelegate.m`

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id> *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
> return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
> continueUserActivity:userActivity
> restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
> }

This should work irrespective of your AppState: `active **OR** background`.

This worked for me as expected! Give it a try. This is should definitely work.

Thanks in advance!